# List sorting incorrect when items are added to Vuex store inside a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a weird situation where I'm rendering a list of sorted results (by a score property) into the UI and the ordering is all over the place.

I have:

- An api call for a list of places
- A for loop over them making an api call for full details within a `setTimeout` to stagger calls to the api. With the full details an 'add' commit  pushes it into an array in the Vuex store
- The UI renders the places from a getter sorting by a score property
- When each place is added to the UI another api call is triggered for the place's score, eventually setting it with 'setScore' commit

With the `setTimeout` is in place the list ordering is all over the place. When it's not there the ordering is as expected. I was using a computed property doing the sorting but moved it into a getter - no diff.

Is there something about using Vuex with `setTimeout` that I should be aware of? Should I be using actions even though the synchronicity of my commit's shouldn't matter?

I attempted to boil this down to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benmccallum/wc270012/), but it works there.

In my [real app](https://github.com/benmccallum/blip) it doesn't... See `setTimeout` line in question [here](https://github.com/benmccallum/blip/blob/fcbff32a002883562dab26a5bd53e3adb21534d5/src/components/Radar.vue#L258).

Comment: I tried replacing `setTimeout` with an npm package that throttles requests and got the same behaviour. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

Comment: You should always use the `key` attribute with `v-for`.

Comment: Thanks @EricGuan. I am in my app, though not in the fiddle (will update).